# importing contents of csv file every hour

Tags: logging, csv

I have a log file that is being written to every few minutes. i will have a process that will listen on a specific directory. every hour it will import new rows from this csv file into an access database. Unfortunately the csv file has no unique key for every row.

The question is how am I supposed to keep track of the new rows to import?

How do I know when to import new rows?

Another complication is that there is another program that deletes this csv file once per day, so i cannot keep track exactly which position i left off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log file naturally should have timestamp. You can track by last loaded log datetime stamp.

If you don't have datetime or any other sequential property to track, you can track file length after each load. So the next time before you read, you set current filestream reader position to the value of file length captured on the previous check.

**[Edit]**

Regarding to the comment that you added about 'another complication' that there is another program that deletes this csv file once per day:

- first of all you need to make sure that this program runs after the tool that imports the content, otherwise you will have a case when file is already deleted, but files tail isn't imported yet
- secondly, I guess that newly created log file will be much smaller as the previous file, so you can easily tell that log was rolled over. Depending on how the file is deleted you might want to use file creation date time as Eric suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If the log file has no unique key, then you are pretty much stuck using the row number as the key.  (Using the filestream reader position, as @Alex Aza suggested, will be more efficient, but it sounds like you are a bit stuck so starting with the row number might get you going and then you can improve it.)

You say you can't use a position because the file will get deleted overnight, but you can handle this as a special case.  If the total number of rows (or last file position) available is less than the previous farthest location you read from, then you'll need to go back to zero.  You should also be able to use the file's creation-time to detect if it's been replaced since you last looked.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, you should take a step back - what is it you are actually logging?

There must be *something* unique, otherwise it wouldn't matter if the record was inserted twice.

To answer your questions:

1. You need a way to map each unique row.  You have said it is a log file, so I'm assuming you aren't editing (or updating) already inserted records.
2. How do you know when to import new rows?  Obviously you don't.  You will need to run this process each time and see if the row hasn't been added.
3. How important is this data?  If it was something such as credit card transactions, you wouldn't be deleting it!  If it was say a log file from a telephone system then why not archive the data?